# IntelliJ implement method for all enum values

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Given I have an 'empty' interface:

```
public interface Color {
}
```

And an enum class that implements said interface:

```
public enum Fruits implements Color  {

    APPLE,
    APRICOT,
    AVOCADO,
    BANANA,
    BLACKBERRY,
    BLUEBERRY,
    CHERRY,
    COCONUT,
    CRANBERRY,
    DATE,
    DURIAN,
    ELDERBERRY,
    FIG,
    JACKFRUIT,
    KIWI,
    LEMON,
    LIME,
    LYCHEE,
    MANGO,
    MELLON,
    ORANGE,
    PAPAYA,
    PASSION_FRUIT,
    PEAR,
    PLUM,
    PINEAPPLE,
    POMELO    
}
```

After a while of coding, I come back to that interface and add a method, such as:

```
public interface Color {
    Color getColor();
}
```

IntelliJ Idea will surely tell me that each enum value is ought to implement the newly added method. What I could do now is jump to each enum value (using F2 as a shortcut to jump to each value) and then go for ALT + ENTER to create a default implementation of it.

```
APPLE {
    @Override
    public Color getColor() {
        return null;
    }

},
APRICOT {
    @Override
    public Color getColor() {
        return null;
    }
},
AVOCADO {
    @Override
    public Color getColor() {
        return null;
    }
},
...
```

This gets quickly out of hand once I realize that there are more than just this enum that implement this interface.

---

**Clarification**

I am searching for a ***keyboard shortcut*** in ***IntelliJ Idea***, an IDE which provides functionality to generate code to create the empty method stump of each enum value at once.

***IntelliJ Idea*** does provide such functionality for every single enum value separately, which leads me to the question: Can it be done for all values at once?

Comment: You have a _whole_ lot of repetition there, and it looks like some sort of refactoring or parameterization would make things cleaner.

Comment: It might seem that way. Please understand the above example to explain the issue at hand, nothing else.

Comment: I mean that your enum values tend to be repeating--you're explicitly listing out what looks like some Cartesian product. That's usually not the best way to do that.

Comment: Will you provide an answer to the question if I replace it with differnt kinds of fruits?

Comment: You got it! =) Now, is there a keyboard shortcut for creating all methods on one step instead of moving from each value to the next (F2) and then pressing ALT+ENTER?

Comment: The two answers below were given *before* the OP has added the "Clarification" part. This "Clarification" has substantially changed the question hence my downvote and vote to close.

Comment: @lexicore I fail to see how the clarification part changed the question.The question title: 'IntelliJ ...' is clearly about tooling.

Then there was, from the very beginning, the following text section: "IntelliJ Idea will surely tell me that each enum value is ought to implement the newly added method. What I could do now is jump to each enum value (using F2 as a shortcut to jump to each value) and then go for ALT + ENTER to create a default implementation of it."

Comment: @lexicore It is a shame that I actually have to add a clarification section for people that do not read the question and still coming up with answers, such as yourself. Why in the world would I even add the tag 'Intellij-idea' to the question? Why would I write about keyboard shortcuts such as F2 and ALT+ENTER? Jesus...

Comment: @JohnSmith In [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51052598/1), nothing was pointing to the fact that you were looking for a keyboard shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA. The core of the question was *Isn't there a shorter way to achieve this that let's creates the default method for each and every enum value at once?* which we answered. If you think this interpretation was wrong or not mandated, think again. At least three high-rep users interpreted your question this way, so this is a pretty good chance there's a problem with your question, not us.

Comment: @JohnSmith If you disagree, feel free to take this to http://meta.stackoverflow.com and see what people say.

Comment: @JohnSmith I dare you to take this to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ and see what people say. I personally am not interested in this discussion and would like to ask you to leave me alone, please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no shortcut to do so.

Comment: @baudsp Can you explain how this does not answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Sure... just create a [default method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) on the interface:

```
default String getSomething(Any any) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Nope, that won't do what I am asking for

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the default implementation in the enum class itself instead of in each of the enum values:

```
public enum DirectCallRate implements KeyPerformanceIndicator  {

    COUNT,
    COUNT_ANSWERED,
    COUNT_UNANSWERED,
    COUNT_EXTERNAL,
    COUNT_ANSWERED_EXTERNAL,
    COUNT_UNANSWERED_EXTERNAL,
    COUNT_INTERNAL,
    COUNT_ANSWERED_INTERNAL,
    COUNT_UNANSWERED_INTERNAL,
    COUNT_INBOUND,
    COUNT_ANSWERED_INBOUND,
    COUNT_UNANSWERED_INBOUND,
    COUNT_OUTBOUND,
    COUNT_ANSWERED_OUTBOUND,
    COUNT_UNANSWERED_OUTBOUND,
    COUNT_EXTERNAL_OUTBOUND,
    COUNT_ANSWERED_EXTERNAL_OUTBOUND,
    COUNT_UNANSWERED_EXTERNAL_OUTBOUND,
    COUNT_EXTERNAL_INBOUND,
    COUNT_ANSWERED_EXTERNAL_INBOUND,
    COUNT_UNANSWERED_EXTERNAL_INBOUND,
    COUNT_INTERNAL_OUTBOUND,
    COUNT_ANSWERED_INTERNAL_OUTBOUND,
    COUNT_UNANSWERED_INTERNAL_OUTBOUND,
    COUNT_INTERNAL_INBOUND,
    COUNT_ANSWERED_INTERNAL_INBOUND,
    COUNT_UNANSWERED_INTERNAL_INBOUND;

    @Override
    public String getSomething(Any any) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I think in this case it is a better approach than creating a default method in the interface as the default implementation seems to be primarily related to the enum, not to all other implementors of the interface.

Comment: Nope, that won't do what I am asking for

Comment: Why not? Please explain.

Comment: @JohnSmith: This does *exactly* what you asked for in the question.